# Uber api auth error for v1/requests {"message"=>"Missing scope: request", "code"=>"unauthorized"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uber-api

I am working on uber api in rails and in booking controller I have this code:
    require 'rubygems'

```
require 'httparty'

class BookingsController < ApplicationController
def index
lat = params[:lat].to_s
long = params[:long].to_s
drop_lat = params[:drop_lat].to_s
drop_lng = params[:drop_lng].to_s


ola_body = {
"pickup_lat" => 12.9490936,
"pickup_lng" => 77.6443056,
 "drop_lat" => 12.950279,
"drop_lng" => 77.641938,
"pickup_mode" => "NOW",
"category" => "auto"
 }
ola_headers = {
"Authorization" => "Bearer TOKEN", 
"X-APP-TOKEN" => "TOKEN"
}
uber_body = {

"product_id" => "7e86473c-5f57-4bd8-b465-07b3eec9e633",
"start_latitude" => 37.761492,
"start_longitude" => -122.423941,
"end_latitude"=> 37.775393,
"end_longitude"=> -122.417546

 }
uber_headers = {
'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
 "Authorization" => "Bearer TOKEN"
  }
 @uber_ride_request = HTTParty.post("
 https://api.uber.com/v1/requests",
 :params => uber_body  ,
 :headers => uber_headers ).parsed_response

  @ola_booking = HTTParty.post(
  "http://sandbox-t.olacabs.com/v1/bookings/create ", 
  :body => ola_body,
  :headers => ola_headers
   ).parsed_response

  respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => JSON.parse(@uber_ride_request) }
  format.json { render :json => JSON.parse(@ola_booking) }
  format.html { render "index.html.erb" }

end

end
end
```

Ola booking request gives appropriate response but when working with uber its giving me an error {"message"=>"Missing scope: request", "code"=>"unauthorized"} . What can be the possible reasons for that?

Comment: This usually means your app isn't configured to obtain the `request` scope from its users. You must first request approval from Uber's Developer Platform team. Look for the "Request Full Access" button next to the list of scopes in the "Authorizations" tab of your developer dashboard.

Comment: It looks like you are requesting simultaneous rides on both platforms. It is against the TOS of the Uber Developer Platform to integrate Uber along side competitors and specifically against our TOS to request rides on the Uber platform and a competitors at the same time.